# node.js modules - exporting both the object and it's properties as functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'd like to have a module which exports functions like this:

```
var log = require("log.js");
log("hello");       // should run console.log("hello")
log.info("world");  // should run console.log("world")
```

What would the contents of log.js be to achieve this? I've tried tampering with the module.exports object but can't seem to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function logger (data) {
    console.log(data);
}

logger.info = function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}

exports = module.exports = logger;
```

Instead of writing the same function again, you can also do

```
logger.info = logger;
```

If you are interested to know more about `module.exports` and `exports`, read [this](http://www.thefourtheye.in/2014/03/nodejs-modules-and-exports.html) blog entry of mine.

Comment: Yep that's it! it was so simple after all. And I thought I'd need getters :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.log = function(msg) { 
    console.log(msg);
}
exports.info = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
}
```

Another way of doing it.

Comment: Won't that require `log.log(message)`?

Comment: Wouldn't that require it to be accessed as `log.log()` ?